# Clion compile with -O3

Tags: c++, clion

I'm writing a c++ program using CLion and I need to specify -O3 flag on the compiler, using `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}" -O3)` on the CMakeList file does not work.
Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either `add_compile_options(-O3)` to add it globally or `target_compile_options(YourTarget -O3)` to add it locally to a specific target.

---

You could also do it by using `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` but that is a pretty old way of doing things in CMakeLists files, that's how it would look like:
`set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O3")` or `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O3)`.

Comment: Where should I put the `target_compile_options`?

Comment: @QianChen Anywhere after you created your target with `add_executable`/`add_library`